# omp parallel for : How to make threads write to private arrays and merge all the arrays once all the threads finished processing

Tags: c++, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a requirement to calculate `z` values, push them into arrays `B` and `s2`.

I tried to parallelize the processing using `omp parallel for`.

One problem I see is, If I don't put `B[i][j] += z` and `s2[i] += z` statements in `critical` section, I see lot of `NaN` values being generated.

Just wondering if there is a way to write the `z` values to separate arrays (one array per thread) and merge them at the end.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    double z;
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int t=1; t<n; t++) {
        double phi_i[N];
        double obs_j_seq_t[N];

        for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
                z=phi_i[i]*trans[i*N + j]*obs_j_seq_t[j]*beta[t*N+j]/c[t]; 
                #pragma omp critical
                { 
                    B[i][j] += z;
                    s2[i] += z;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why use the preprocessot if you can use `std::async`?

Comment: Have you tried to use `omp atomic` for each `z` accumulation? It is way better than using critical sections, specially when there is no collision (threads accessing different positions). On the other hand, are you trying to divide the nested for loops iterations among all threads? Currently, each thread is executing all the iterations in parallel. You might consider using `#pragma omp for collapse(2)` there.

Answer (score 2):

Your code exposes a few issues, each being a potential killer for its performance and / or validity:

- You start by using a `#pragma omp parallel` and then you add a `#pragma omp parallel for`. That means that you are trying to generate nested parallelism (a parallel region within another parallel region). This is first, a bad idea and second, disabled by default. Therefore, your second `parallel` directive is ignored and the work on your loop never gets distributed and is executed in full by all the threads you spawned with your initial `parallel` directive. Therefore, you have race conditions on the writing of the results in `B` and `s2` by all the threads at once. You solve the issue by adding a `critical` section, but fundamentally, the code is wrong.
- Even if you hadn't had this initial `parallel` directive or with nested parallelism enabled, your code would have been wrong for the following reasons:

  - Your `z` variable is `shared` across the threads of the second `parallel` region and since it is modified by all of them, its value is undefined as soon as more than one thread is spawned in the region.
  - Even more fundamentally, you try to parallelize the loop over `t`, but the solutions are indexed over `i`. That means that all threads will compete for updating the same indexes, leading once more to race conditions and invalid results. You could again use a `critical` directive to address that, but that would only make the code super slow. You'd better be parallelizing the loop over `i` (while possibly swapping the loops over `t` and `i` to put the latter the outermost one).

Your code could become something like this (not tested):

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    for(int t=1; t<n; t++) {
        double phi_i[N];       // I guess these need some initialization
        double obs_j_seq_t[N]; // Idem
        for(int j=0; j<N; j++) {
            double z=phi_i[i]*trans[i*N + j]*obs_j_seq_t[j]*beta[t*N+j]/c[t]; 
            B[i][j] += z;
            s2[i] += z;
        }
    }
}
```